# mod_rewrite search feature, problem with slash (404 error)

Tags: regex, apache, search, mod-rewrite, slash

I'm trying to rewrite search results page url to something like /search/query-1.html
but when I try searching for a keyword that has a slash "/" or "#" .. (e.g A/D) it returns a 404 error.

My .htaccess has the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?search=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

What can be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show an example URL that doesn't work

Comment: Hi, This one works http://localhost/search/test/abc-1.html and this one not (url encoded query): http://localhost/search/test%2Fabc-1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want Apache to accept encoded slashes like you mentioned in the comments, you'll have to enable it in your server configuration using the [`AllowEncodedSlashes` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes):

```
AllowEncodedSlashes on
```

You likely don't have this enabled now, and the default behaviour in that case is for Apache to reject the request with a 404 response. You can only specify this directive in a server or virtual host context, so depending on your environment you might not be able to change this. As far as the encoded hash symbol goes, it shouldn't have any problem handling that.

However, it *is* likely that the hash is inserted into the query string decoded, which might cause some issues. If you find that to be the case and your Apache installation is new enough, you should add the [`B` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) to your `RewriteRule` to ensure that the backreference is escaped appropriately:

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?search=$1&page=$2 [B,L]
```

Comment: The B flag is what I needed, I can manipulate the GET request using php.. Thanks :)